# Verify password Mono + IPA(LDAP) + rhel

Tags: c#, mono, ldap, rhel

I need to verify user/password in LDAP (inside IPA). This is example from Novell, but not working

```
System.String ldapHost = "ipa-server.ipadev.local";
            System.String loginDN = "uid=tom,cn=users,cn=compat,dc=ipadev,dc=local";
            System.String password = "12345678";
            System.String objectDN = "cn=tim,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=ipadev,dc=local";
            System.String testPassword = "12345678";
            LdapConnection conn = new LdapConnection();
            conn.SecureSocketLayer = true;
            conn.UserDefinedServerCertValidationDelegate += delegate {
                return true;
            };

            try
            {
                conn.Connect(ldapHost, LdapConnection.DEFAULT_SSL_PORT);
                conn.Bind(loginDN, password);

                LdapAttribute attr = new LdapAttribute("userPassword", testPassword);
                bool correct = conn.Compare(objectDN, attr);

                System.Console.Out.WriteLine(correct ? "The password is correct." : "The password is incorrect.\n");

                // disconnect with the server
                conn.Disconnect();
            }
            catch (LdapReferralException ex) 
            {
                System.Console.Error.WriteLine ("Error: Referrals exception - " + ex.ToString());
                System.Console.Error.WriteLine ("Referrals: " + ex.getReferrals ());
            }
            catch (LdapException e)
            {
                if (e.ResultCode == LdapException.NO_SUCH_OBJECT)
                {
                    System.Console.Error.WriteLine("Error: No such entry - " + e.ToString());
                }
                else if (e.ResultCode == LdapException.NO_SUCH_ATTRIBUTE)
                {
                    System.Console.Error.WriteLine("Error: No such attribute");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Console.Error.WriteLine("Error: " + e.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException e)
            {
                System.Console.Out.WriteLine("Error: " + e.ToString());
            }
            System.Environment.Exit(0);
```

If I use an empty password - bind will be successful, but `conn.Compare` gives an error - `Error: LdapException: (50) Insufficient Access Rights`

if I use the normal password (12345678), I get - `error "LdapReferralException: (10) Referral"` inside Bind

And one more question - inside loginDn should I use full path like `"uid=tom,cn=users,cn=compat,dc=ipadev,dc=local"`, but user only owns login, how to create this full path?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you do it in LDAP. The idea is to connect *as* that user with that password, and see if it succeeds.

Comment: Do you mean connect (Bind) as "tim" (tom, it doesn't matter) and his password? I'am try to do this, but always have an error - "LdapException: (32) No Such Object". And what to do, if i dont know full path "uid=tom,cn=users,cn=compat,dc=ipadev,dc=local", only uid and dc ? And if I enter incorrect password, all the same bind succefu